# repetitive instructions bash script

Tags: bash, loops, scripting

This could easily be any lang...but I'm using bash for now. I'm looking for the understanding behind this that can be replicated across langs.

so...

I'm copying a file up the directory tree and than replacing that file with another.

```
     cp "$DIR"/folder2/file2 "$DIR";
     mv "$DIR"/folder1/file1 "$DIR"/folder2/file2;
```

Then I take the copied file and move it into another folder..starting the same dance.

```
     cp "$DIR"/folder3/file3 "$DIR";
     mv "$DIR"/file2 "$DIR"/folder3/file3
```

I want to do this like 100 times+.

what's the most elegant way?

Elegant, in the sense of brief and understandable by someone else.

Comment: What's changing between the iterations? Can you post a sample of the repeated commands you want to turn into a loop?

Comment: FYI -- non-environment variables should be lower-case, so as to not conflict with environment variables and reserved names. Thus `$dir`, not `$DIR`.

Comment: wow...i was just trying to figure out how to distinguish my env variables from the non's...u must b a ghost

Comment: Why are you using `cp` for the first step, when the next step is to replace (and delete) the original file? It looks like you should be using `mv` for both steps.

Comment: point taken..but besides correctness is there an improvement on the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to:

1. Backup file B.
2. Rename (or move) file A as file B.
3. Backup file C.
4. Rename backup of file B as file C.
5. Backup file D.
6. Rename backup of file C as file D.

and so on.

It's actually easier to do it backwards such that you only need to backup the last file.

```
last=100
mv "$DIR/folder$last/file$last" "$DIR"
for i in $(seq $last -1 2); do
  mv "$DIR/folder$((i-1))/file$((i-1))" "$DIR/folder$i/file$i"
done
```

Note:

- `seq $last -1 2` generates a sequence of numbers from `$last` up to `2` by increments of `-1`.
- I'm using `seq` instead of brace expansion because the latter doesn't expand numbers when you have `{$last .. 1}`

Answer (score 5):

```
for i in {1..100}; do
    j=$((i+1))

    cp "$DIR"/folder$j/file$j "$DIR"
    mv "$DIR"/folder$i/file$i "$DIR"/folder$j/file$j
done
```

Comment: A slightly cleaner alternative to incrementing is `((i++))`.

Comment: I wish this solution worked as I desired but it does get the same results if I continue the iteration manually...it constantly deletes evthing in the folders